# Redirect to another page with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very very new to Angular so I would like to apologize for this question up front.

I have this Angular script that sends a POST request and in the fail section I would like to redirect the user to another page.
This is the structure of the site

-login folder
  js folder
     controllers.js
  login.html
  login.css
-index.html

My Angular code id in controllers.js. I use the code in the login.html. I need to redirect the user from login.html to index.html. This unfortunately doesn't work, when it goes in the error part of the code it doesn't redirect the user.

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('WebApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.login = function($location){
    $scope.incorrectPass = false;
    $http.post('service link', {'email': $scope.username, 'password': $scope.password, 'UUID': 'dknasklaxcaosdhdajkshnjk', 'platform': 1})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("request success");
    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
      $scope.$apply(function() { $location.path("/index.html"); });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you only use Javascript `location.href` to redirect your page if it fails to load request, I think this will return what you want to do! :)

Comment: I hope in your routeProvider or stateProvide you have route to index.html. It never works like this. You should have route to .html page

Comment: do you see any error? and Have your configured your route provider?

Comment: I don't have any routing or route provider. But it works fine with clean javascript. So I think I will use that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope in your routeProvider or stateProvide you have route to index.html. It never works like this. You should have route to .html page

```
 .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
   .when("/home", {
        title: 'home',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'HomeController as homeCtrl'
    }) 
   .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
```

Now if you do

```
    $location.path("/home");
```

in your login/js/controller.js file, it shall work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for redirection
$window.location.href = '/index.html';